# How does one call standard native methods in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am an Android beginner. And I'd like to write some java classes that utilize existing Android native methods. As a simple example, I tried exposing the floor method from within the FloatMath class. However, this forces the app closed. I have copied my code below. It is pretty simple and is targeted at v1.6. So may I ask if there is something obvious I a missing? Do I need to import any special libraries or compilers?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static native float floor(float value);  

    float inputFloat = (float) 2.3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        float outputFloat = floor(inputFloat);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you like to do with your function ? if you want to use the fnc you can do it with `double myvar = Math.floor(arg);`

Comment: Why not just call `Math.floor`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do this way.

In JNI (Java Native Interface), native methods are linked to a specific class by their name.

In your case, you would need to define a native library, e.g. `libfoo.so`, that has an exported function called `Java_com_example_app_MainActivity_floor` (com.example.app is the package name). You then load the library via `System.loadLibrary("foo")` and only then that method will be available.

One way to call functions from other native libraries (aside from Java Reflection on their corresponding Java class), is to load the library from C/C++ and wrap its functions (via `dlopen`, `dlsym` etc.).

Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, I can't be more specific.

Read more about the JNI and native development here: https://code.google.com/p/awesomeguy/wiki/JNITutorial (a bit outdated but the JNI part still holds)

Comment: That exactly answers my question. Thank you. My ultimate goal is to create a modified JetPlayer class without the singleton limitation. Not as easy as you might think since the constructor is private. I figure I can A) Use reflection to perform direct class surgery on JetPlayer in java or B) Write a custom JetPlayer using the same underlying methods. Based on your answer, Option B is probably impractical as it seems I'd need to perform dlopen on libmedia.so - thus opening the platform genie bottle. OTOH, reflection hardly seems appealing.

Comment: Hopefully this isn't off topic, but the following reflective code appears to work for making multiple JetPlayer instances. Although it feels like a hack and a half. Constructor <JetPlayer> jetFactory = JetPlayer.class.getDeclaredConstructor();jetFactory.setAccessible(true); JetPlayer multiJet = jetFactory.newInstance();

Comment: No reason that shouldn't work **but** bear in mind that's it was obviously meant to be a singleton, so you might be breaking concurrency assumptions in back end stores, if you use more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the letter `f`

```
float inputFloat = (float) 2.3f;
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question.